# How to read batch hdf5 files in c++

Tags: c++, hdf5

I have 400 hdf5 files. I need read them to use some data in these files to simulation. How to write  in a simple way?

I just write a function to read. But it didn't work well

Comment: "I just write a function to read. But it didn't work well" - Show us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and tell us how it didn't work well.

Comment: You probably need to start with this example here: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue by doing the following using [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com) in C++ (assuming that your HDF5 files are stored in a directory named `data` and that each file has a dataset named `dset` containing 10 integers):

```
// declare variables
std::stringstream script;
int values[10];
char *file;

// register variable 'values' for subsequent usage (by HDFql), which will store values from dataset 'dset'
HDFql::variableRegister(&values);

// retrieve files stored in directory '/data' (where HDF5 files are hypothetical stored)
HDFql::execute("SHOW FILE /data/");

// read and process dataset 'dset' from each file retrieved
while(HDFql::cursorNext() == HDFql::Success)
{
    // get file name
    file = HDFql::cursorGetChar();
    std::cout << "File found: " << file << std::endl;

    // prepare script to read dataset 'dset' and populate variable 'values' with it
    script.str("");
    script << "SELECT FROM /data/" << file << " dset INTO MEMORY " << HDFql::variableGetNumber(&values);

    // execute script
    HDFql::execute(script);

    // process variable 'values'
    // (...)
}
```

For additional info check the [reference manual](https://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) and [examples](https://www.hdfql.com/examples) that illustrate HDFql functionalities.